# Comparison of components and classes between Angular Bootstrap vs Angular Material Design for Migration

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, angular-ui-bootstrap, angular-material

Well, I know that **Bootstrap** and **Angular Material Design** are two differents framework's, but I also know that they have many similarities and it is possible to make a comparison of alternatives to use between classes and components.

For example:

```
╔═══════════════╦═════════════╦════════════════╦═══════════════════════╗
║   Bootstrap   ║  Material   ║ Bootstrap Type ║ Angular Material Type ║
╠═══════════════╬═════════════╬════════════════╬═══════════════════════╣
║ .btn          ║ <md-button> ║ class          ║ directive/tag         ║
║ .btn-link     ║             ║ class          ║                       ║
║ .btn-primary  ║ .md-primary ║ class          ║ class                 ║
║ .nav.nav-tabs ║ <md-tabs>   ║ class          ║ directive/tag         ║
╚═══════════════╩═════════════╩════════════════╩═══════════════════════╝
```

My idea is to migrate in the best possible way between Bootstrap and AMD using an alternative for each component and CSS class.

So, could you share your knowledge with recommendations, reference websites or even examples of codes?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Your question is very broad, But i will tell you in a nutshell Bootsrap drives look/feel/layouts based on css classes only. while Angular Material drives the look/feel/layouts based on directives (programatically), yes there is css included with angular material as well, that is not the main driver.

I feel that you are maybe wasting time in trying to archive a clear migration paths between the two. essentially you are looking at a new practice all together.

Responsive design vs MVC design that contains responsive directives